# Android Invalidate() each time a loop occurs

Tags: android, invalidation

I am a game dev beginner and I am currently having trouble with my game....
I would like the game to update the canvas each time I loop in order to show my character move in a single press of an image... Invalidate() does not work for me here since it only displays the end position of my character
Here is the code for it:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int x = (int)event.getX();
    final int y = (int)event.getY();
    int action = event.getAction();

switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if (rollbounds.contains((int)x, (int)y))
            {
                //dice roll
                Random rand = new Random();

                move = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

                //end of dice roll
                //move counting

                for (int loop=move;loop>0;loop--)
                {
                if ((charypos >= 220)&&(charxpos == 9))
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    loop=1;
                }
                if (charxpos != 205&&charLeftMove==false)
                {

                    for (int loop2 = 28;loop2>0;loop2--)
                    {
                        charxpos+=1;
                        //update or invalidate here

                    }
```

This here is a board game where when I touch the roll button, I would get the character to move the number of spaces smoothly, since invalidate causes it to move to the end position instantly.
Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: try to use postInvalidate, and I would try to get the smooth movement outside the onTouchEvent , maybe on the onDraw, testing if I need to move again and re-invalidate (like the scroll effect : if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
   int deltaX = actualX - mPrevX;
   postInvalidate();
}

Comment: given my code above, would you please give me an example code?
I am a beginner so I seriously need stuff to go on before I would be able to try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the touch event is actually in UI thread? Even if you called the invalidate, the canvas will not draw anything until your whole code block has been executed. That means the system will render the UI after your code

```
for (int loop=move;loop>0;loop--)
```

that's why you found always move to the end position. You should move your code to 
`case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`. Don't use loop in an event. just make calculation once by every touch event. For example, globally declare a variable, and increase value by touchEvent

```
int a = 0;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int x = (int)event.getX();
    final int y = (int)event.getY();
    int action = event.getAction();

switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                ++a;
                invalidate();
```

Comment: I was able to grasp what you said yushullx but i can't seem to find a way to apply it to my game.
What I want to happen is the character to move to the position given by the dice roll on a single touch...

Comment: you can use a handler to send message to UI thread for drawing.  check Android doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html